# Wamp 403 forbidden, when setting up zend framework

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, http-status-code-403

I am actually trying to install zend framework on WAMP. I followed the instruction on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=41-qEbpG2XQ). I have encountered a problem. I setup Zend Framework in the directory C:\websites\test. I edited the file C:\wampzend\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf according to the instructions in the tutorial:

```
<Directory c:/websites>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wampzend/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/test/public"
    ServerName test
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also edited my hosts file and entered a pointer from test to 127.0.0.1. If I go to the url test I get a 403 Forbidden response. localhost which points to wampzend/www works fine. Any solutions for the 403 response?

Comment: What does your error log say? Most often you find more info there why the 403 has been given.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, the allocation of directory access rights really belongs inside the  ...  definition and should be specific to that VHOST.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wampzend/www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "c:/wampzend/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/websites/test/public"
    ServerName test
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "c:/websites/test/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Using `Allow from all` is definitely over kill, especially as you are just developing and not giving access to the world.
It wont actually give access to the world, unless you port forward your router, but when you try that, its best that only the sites you actually want to be visible to the world are.